# Export data with the number form but is not same as shown in notebook

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I want to export data nicely with NumberForm, However it displays Ok in the note book, but not the exported file.

Here is the code:

```
lst = {{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}};
lst = N[lst, 10]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["testlst.txt", lst, "Table"];
```

The output in the notebook is:

```
{{0.1000000000, 0.3333333333}, {0.3333333333, 3.141592654}}
```

However in the txt file it looks like(ugly, not easy to read):

```
0.1 0.3333333333
0.3333333333    3.141592654
```

**How to fix this?** or **How to achieve the format specification such as `%15.4lf` like in `c`?**

Comment: `lst = NumberForm[lst // N, {11, 10}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon but you can't export it in the table form

Comment: Your statement that "The output in the notebook is: `{{0.1000000000, `..." is simply wrong. What we get in the Notebook is: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WGJr7.png). Please correct your question formulation.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I miss a 10 in the code after the comma

Comment: The `ToString` command appears to preserve format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I mapped `NumberForm`, padding to the left with spaces and to the right with zeroes, at the lowest level of your table

```
numbers = 
  Map[
    NumberForm[#, {11, 10}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] &, 
    N[{{1/10, 1/3}, {1/3, Pi}}, 10], 
    {-1}]
```

and then exported it to my desktop

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.txt"}], numbers, "Table"]
```

The output file looked like this:

[image: file]

which I think is pretty much what you want.

Comment: (+1) But this solution works only starting from *Mathematica* version 9.