# Exporting formatted numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I would like to format numbers of a list and write them in columns to file.

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
dir = NotebookDirectory[];

Export[StringJoin[dir, "list1.dat"], list, "Table"];
```

The content of file `list1.dat` is (a single line):

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

When the numbers are formatted:

```
Export[StringJoin[dir, "list2.dat"], NumberForm[list, {5, 4}], "Table"];
```

The content of file `list2.dat` is:

```
{{1.0000, 2.0000}, {3.0000, 4.0000}, {5.0000, 6.0000}}
```

How can I get the content of `list2.dat` to be?:

```
1.0000 2.0000
3.0000 4.0000
5.0000 6.0000
```

UPDATE:

What would be the solution for:

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
```

to get with same formatting:

```
1.0000 2.0000 3.0000 4.0000
5.0000 6.0000 7.0000 8.0000
```

Comment: Does this work: `Map[NumberForm[#, {5, 4}] &, list, {2}]`?

Comment: Yes ... thank you ... this solves my problem

Comment: @Kuba: Can you put this and if you have solution for the UPDATE to a answer, so that I can accept it as solution?

Comment: Or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102846/5478

Comment: @Kuba: http://imgur.com/jiYkq5B

Comment: `Join @@@ {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
data = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
```

then

```
formatted = Map[NumberForm[#, {5, 4}] &, ArrayReshape[data, {2, 4}], {-1}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.dat"}], formatted, "Table"];
FilePrint[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.dat"}]]
```

prints

[image: data]